# What is the error in this if statement of python code

Tags: python-3.x

```py
num=int(input("ENter number between 10 and 20"))

if num>=10:

    elif num<=20:

        print("THank you")

else:

     print("Incorrect")
```

Comment: I think your first two lines should be combined to if num>=10 and num<20:

Comment: Good question, what **is** the error?

Comment: Also, the indentation is broken and I can't tell if it's part of the issue or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are trying to perform the below operation. Your code has improper use of conditional statement.

```
num=int(input("Enter a number between 10 and 20: "))
if num>=10 and num<=20:
    print("Thank you")

else:
    print("Incorrect")
```